# How to do Parallel filtering

Tags: f#, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, plinq

How do I achieve parallel filtering in F#? Basically I want to do `Array.Parallel.Choose` except with a sequence expression to create an Array.

I tried:

```
Async.Parallel [for x in 1..40 do yield async { if x % 5 = 0 then return x }]
```

but this is a type mismatch since the if doesn't always have a value (i.e. `Async<unit>` isn't an `Async<'a>`).

I'm iterating over a large set of numbers (1,000,000,000 +) so I don't want to generate the sequence upfront.

The actual check in the if statement is:

```
let isPalindrome (x : int) = let numberArray = x.ToString().ToCharArray()
                             numberArray = Array.rev numberArray
```

Tried using PSeq:

```
[for x in 990000..999999 do for y in 990000..999999 do yield (x, y, x*y)]
|> PSeq.filter(fun (x, y, z) -> isPalindrome z)
|> Seq.max
```

this results in an `OutOfMemoryException`.

Ugly workaround:

```
let numberArray = [|990000..999999|]
let result = numberArray |> Array.Parallel.collect(fun x -> [| for y in numberArray do if isPalindrome (x*y) then yield (x, y, x*y)|])
             |> Array.maxBy(fun (x, y, z) -> z)
```

Comment: There's a `PSeq` (Parallel Sequence) module in the F# PowerPack, have you tried it? Also, I doubt you'll achieve much (if any) performance improvement by using a parallel sequence if you're just doing a simple `mod` in your filter...

Comment: @ildjarn The `mod` is just a placeholder.  I'm actually playing with my solution to Project Euler problem 4 http://projecteuler.net/problem=4 to see how much I can get it to scale.  I was hoping to avoid external libraries.

Comment: @ildjarn I looked at `PSeq` but it doesn't appear to do what I need: i.e. it works with existing sequences rather than with sequence generation

Comment: You understand that sequences are lazy, right? Have a `seq` generator, and use `PSeq` for filtering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let isPalindrome (x : int) = let numberArray = x.ToString().ToCharArray()
                             numberArray = Array.rev numberArray
```

I figured out how to use the `PSeq` library to do lazy filtering on a sequence:

```
let generator =
    seq {
        for x in 990000..999999 do 
            for y in 990000..999999 do 
                yield (x, y, x*y) 
    }

generator
|> PSeq.filter(fun (x, y, z) -> isPalindrome z)
|> Seq.max
```

Real: 00:00:28.938, CPU: 00:01:49.078, GC gen0: 3448, gen1: 2, gen2: 0

Sadly, this was slower than my ugly hack:

```
let numberArray = [|990000..999999|]
let result = numberArray |> Array.Parallel.collect(fun x -> [| for y in numberArray do if isPalindrome (x*y) then yield (x, y, x*y)|])
             |> Array.maxBy(fun (x, y, z) -> z)
```

Real: 00:00:24.779, CPU: 00:01:32.109, GC gen0: 2680, gen1: 18, gen2: 1

Comment: @ildjarn Ouch... its going to take me some time to understand that!

Answer (score 0):

A much more efficient solution based on the implementation of Array.Choose:

```
 open System.Collections.Concurrent
 open System.Threading.Tasks
 open System


 let parallelFilter f (array: 'T[]) = 

            let inputLength = array.Length                      

            let isChosen : bool [] = Array.zeroCreate inputLength                
            let mutable outputLength = 0        
            let range = Partitioner.Create(0,inputLength)
            Parallel.ForEach(
                         range,
                         (fun () ->0),
                         (fun (start,finish) _ count -> 
                            let mutable localCount = 0
                            for i in start .. finish-1 do
                                match f array.[i] with 
                                | true -> () 
                                | false -> 
                                    isChosen.[i] <- true                                      
                                    localCount <- localCount+1
                            localCount),
                          Action<int> (fun x -> System.Threading.Interlocked.Add(&outputLength,x) |> ignore )
                          ) |> ignore         

            let output = Array.zeroCreate outputLength
            let mutable curr = 0
            for i = 0 to isChosen.Length-1 do 
                if isChosen.[i] then 
                    output.[curr] <- output.[i]
                    curr <- curr + 1
            output
```